# Is it possible to retrieve an iOS 7 style receipt from iOS 6 style receipt data?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation, in-app-subscription

I have an iOS app that offers in-app subscriptions. We were originally unwittingly using the now-deprecated `transactionReceipt` field on `SKPaymentTransaction`. (This was unfortunately what was provided via a third-party library we were using.) When, from our server, we call into Apple's validation service, it returns "iOS 6 style" receipt data.

We're now changing our code to use the receipt data provided inside the app bundle. Submitting this to Apple's validation service yields an "iOS 7 style" receipt.

Since we can't ensure that every copy of the app out there is updated, we have to be able to accept the "iOS 6 style" receipts that our app submits to our server. However, it would be really great if, on the server side, we could somehow use these to retrieve the newer "iOS 7 style" receipts.

I tried re-submitting the base64-encoded data that appears in the `latest_receipt` field from the response from Apple's validation service for an iOS 6 style receipt, but it appears you just get the same data again.

**Is there anything we can do to request the full iOS 7 style receipt using only the iOS 6 style receipt data we have?**